# Using Axios to play sound from an URL using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, axios

I'm trying to use axios to play sound from a url

```
soundUrl = `https://cdn.freesound.org/previews/213/213889_2287873-lq.ogg`
const response = await axios.get(soundUrl, {
        responseType: 'stream',
      });

      if (response.status === 200) {
        // Create a Speaker instance to play the sound
        const speaker = new Speaker();
        // Pipe the response data stream directly to the speaker
        response.data.pipe(speaker);
}
```

However, all this does is play a static noise.

I also tried to download the file directly from this download link: https://freesound.org/people/Counter-gamer/sounds/213889/download/213889__counter-gamer__the-cats-meow.wav

using axios, then playing the downloaded file, but the audio is not successfully downloaded.

I also tried using this:

```
player.play(soundUrl, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Error playing audio:', err);
        } else {
          console.log('Audio played successfully');
        }
      });
```

Comment: might be a problem with the fileformat, or the way to stream it, or the "Speaker" library you are using really.

Comment: How can I add authentication in my code?

Answer (score 1):

For programmatic use of Freesound you have to use their API; a direct URL will not work.
Start with the simplest method:

1. obtain an [apikey](https://freesound.org/apiv2/apply)
2. add auth data in your axios request

There are two methods available to add auth data:

A) In your `soundUrl`, like so: `https://cdn.freesound.org/previews/213/213889_2287873-lq.ogg?token=YOUR_API_KEY"`

B) In headers:

```js
const response = await axios.get(soundUrl, {
  responseType: 'stream',
  headers: { "Authorization": "Token YOUR_API_KEY"},
      });
[...]
```

Comment: Hi, I tried both methods to add my API key, but when I run the code, only static plays. I think it is still not getting the audio from the website.

Comment: Please share what are your console errors. If axios request is failing, there will be useful infos there